Potential attained by a sphere under illumination

A silver sphere of radius 1 cm and work function 4.7 eV is suspended from an insulating thread in free-space. It is under continuous illumination of 200 nm wavelength light. As photoelectrons are emitted, the sphere gets charged and acquires a potential. The maximum number of photoelectrons emitted from the sphere is $A \cdot 10^z$ (where $1 < A < 10$). The value of $z$ is what ?

My doubt is in this question the maximum potential attained by the sphere is equated with the stopping potential of the electron emitted. Why do we equate the two?

As the sphere loses electrons, electrons begin to feel an electrostatic attraction to the sphere. When the electric potential attained by the sphere is equal to the maximum kinetic energy of the electron, then no more electrons will be emitted. You can think of the sphere as an anode that is providing an opposing electrostatic force on the electrons. The potential of this anode, when no further charges are emitted is exactly the stopping voltage. Thus the stopping voltage is the maximum potential of the sphere.

In the conventional photoelectric effect, the stopping potential is the potential difference between the metal surface and the collecting electrode such that no current can reach the collecting electrode.  In other words, the electrons are not emitted from the metal with sufficient energy to reach the collecting electrode, because the change in potential energy between metal and collector is too great.
In this current problem, the same basic principle applies.  To escape the sphere, the emitted electrons have to have enough kinetic energy to get infinitely far away from the sphere.  The amount of kinetic energy they need itself can be related to the electric potential of the sphere, and magnitude-wise it will be the same potential that can stop the current in the conventional photoelectric effect.
